# java: threadsafe data structure (Queue + Map) for storing pending network requests?

Tags: java, data-structures, concurrency, dictionary, queue

I need to use some kind of data structure to store pending network requests.

Ideally I would like a queue which also offers Map access, as the operations are basically as follows:

```
interface PendingRequestStore<K, V>
{
    /* add item to queue with value v and key k */
    void add(K k, V v);
    /* remove and return value of first item in queue, or null if empty */
    V pollFirst();
    /* return the key of the first item in the queue, or null if empty */
    K getFirstKey();
    /* get item with key k, or null if absent */
    V get(K k);        
    /* remove and return value of item in queue with key k, or null if absent */
    V remove(K k);
}
```

The intent is to store pending requests when they are sent out; then, when I get a response, I can remove the request with the specified key. The responses generally don't arrive in the order the requests were sent out. If I could guarantee timely responses, a regular `Map` would be enough for that, but there are occasional failures where I also need to resend orphan requests in the order they were added to the queue. So I'd use a queue *and* a map, but then I need a way to remove items in the middle of the queue when I get responses that are out of order.

If I can't avoid synchronized that's ok, but it would be nice to use a concurrent data structure too.

Any suggestions?

---

*NOTE*: The keys have no ordering so an ordered map e.g. [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) won't help me.

Comment: Have a look at the collection classes in the `java.util.concurrent` package.

Comment: ? Which ones? I'm vaguely familiar w/ j.u.c and none of them seems obviously usable in this case.

Comment: What's wrong with good old LinkedHashMap, `Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap(...))` ?

Comment: Hmm. It has `add`, `get`, and `remove`; how would I implement `getFirstKey()` and an atomic `pollFirst()`?

Comment: With `getFirstKey` using `m.keySet().iterator()` and similarly for `pollFirst`, although they would need to iterate to the end of the list each time, which isn't very efficient

Comment: why would they need to iterate to the end? also, pollFirst would require me to manually synchronize. anyway there's some possibilities....

Comment: Mmmm, not enough sleep, the front of the list is indeed the first insertion, that seems like a good solution then.

Comment: You can avoid synchronization by using a Lock.  Whether this is more efficient will depend on your platform. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe looks very familiar to a LinkedHashMap which isn't synchronized, but it provides the concept of ordering and also maps a key to a value.

Comment: +1.  I don't know of any _concurrent_ class that would help here, so I'd fall back to using LinkedHashedMap and your own synchronisation. getFirstKey() and pollFirst() could be implemented by (synchronized) code that: checks map is not empty; uses iterator().next()

Comment: Agreed -- it does need a bit of wrapping out in own code -- for synchronization reasons first and secondly for providing the methods mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

> So I'd use a queue and a map, but then
>   I need a way to remove items in the
>   middle of the queue when I get
>   responses that are out of order.

If you use a LinkedList as your queue, you can take advantage of it's `remove(Object o)` method. Obviously you'd need to guarantee consistency between the map and queue so some sort of manual synchronization will be required.

Comment: efficiency is the issue here, though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the java.util.concurrent package, specifically the ConcurrentSkipListMap? You will just need to define a comparator that will order them by insertion time.
[ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)

Comment: hmmm... that means I need to add a timestamp field in my data; I'd rather avoid this, but you have a point.

Comment: Or you could use an Atomic Long as a counter.